# Module not found in Angular for declaration d.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write an declaration file for [Leaflet.ActiveLayers](https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers) and include it in Angular service.

Declaration file looks like:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as ActiveLayers from 'leaflet.active-layers';

declare module 'leaflet.active-layers' {
    declare function getActiveBaseLayer();
    declare function getActiveOverlayLayers();
    declare function onAdd();
}
```

and it is saved as `index.d.ts` in `node_module/@types/leaflet.active-layers`

The file is included in Angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Leaflet from 'leaflet';
import * as ActiveLayer from 'leaflet.active-layers';

declare var L: any;

@Injectable()
export class MapService {

  public activeLayer: any;

  constructor() {}
  init() {
    this.activeLayer = ActiveLayer.getActiveBaseLayer();
    console.log(this.activeLayer);
  }
}
```

so I can access getActiveBaseLayer method, but service cannot find the module during compilation:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/leaflet/services/map-service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet.active-layers' in 'C:\project\src\main\webapp\app\leaflet\services'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/leaflet/services/map-service.ts 25:30-62
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/leaflet/leaflet.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
```

Comment: have you added the `leaflet` service module under `import` section of the current module?

Comment: Yes, it's there in imports array

Comment: I think you are missing `export` before `declare module 'leaflet.active-layers' {`

Comment: I can access `getActiveBaseLayer` method even without `export` keyword.